# Vectors misconception correction:

Tags: vectors

> 1. If a vector pointing upward has a positive magnitude, a vector pointing down has a negative magnitude.

Why is this False? Both vectors pointing in different direction, shouldn't it be have different signs, hence different magnitude?

> 2. if vector A - B = 0, then the vector A and B have equal magnitude and are directed in the same direction.

Why is this True? If A point right, B have to point right to 'cancel out' to be zero, this means different direction.

Comment: Do you know how the magnitude of a vector is defined? (You haven’t said anything about it.) You can’t really reason about concepts without knowing and understanding their definitions.

Comment: @Ghoster magnitude of vector is simply the "length of the vector".

Comment: Can a length be negative? Do you know how to compute the length of a vector like (2, -5, 3) *mathematically*?

Comment: Given that for the second question you know if $A$ points right so does $B$, why do you then say the direction is _different_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding the first statement, "magnitude" is the "quantity" of something and vectors with opposite sign can have same "quantity" since it's not depended on direction of vector, for example, if you and your friend are playing tug of war and none of you is being displaced from your initial position, that means that the "quantity" of force that you both are applying is same but due to "opposite" direction the net force becomes zero hence none of you is moving.

now onto the second statement, if we take two vectors
$ \vec{a} \mathbf{,} \vec{b} $ if it is given that $\vec{a}$ - $\vec{b}$ = 0, what this actually shows is that

$\vec{a}$ + ($\vec{-b}$) = 0, and here $\vec{-b}$ represent $\vec{b}$ but in opposite direction, $\Rightarrow$ that the addition of $\vec{a}$  and $\vec{-b}$ will make the resultant zero and this is only possible if $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are in same direction. The example 3 in this image might clear your doubt

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*If a vector pointing upward has a positive magnitude, a vector pointing down has a negative magnitude.*
Magnitude is always positive.
One way of thinking of this is to think of the length (magnitude) of a vector and note that length (magnitude) can only be positive.
A correct statement would be, *If a vector pointing upward has a positive **component** [in a given direction], a vector pointing down has a negative **component** [in the given direction].*

*. . . . . vector A - B = 0 . . . . .*
Let $\hat s$ be a given direction and $\vec A = A \,\hat s$ where $A$ is the magnitude (or component) of $\vec A$ in the $\hat s$ direction and $\vec B = B \,\hat s$ where $B$ is the magnitude (or component) of $\vec B$ in the $\hat s$ direction.

If $\vec A - \vec B = \vec 0$ then $A \,\hat s - B \,\hat s =0\hat s\Rightarrow A-B = 0$, ie $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you imagine a vector as being an arrow, then its magnitude it its *length*, which is inherently positive and does not depend on the direction the arrow points.
2. If $A+B = 0$, then they must point in opposite directions. But we're talking about $A-B$. If $A-B=0$, then $A=B$.